# Set Array method to accept a fixed amount?

Tags: java

I am trying to write an app that will set a fixed array of a any size and then pass that into the method as a parameter.

```
package com.company;

public class NumberManipulation {
    double [] array = {500,250,-350,124,87};
    double minimum = Double.MIN_VALUE;
    double maximum = Double.MAX_VALUE;

    public void getMaximum() {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] > minimum) {
                minimum = array[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(minimum);
    }

    public void getMinimum() {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length ; i++) {
            if (array[i] < maximum){
                maximum = array[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(maximum);
    }
}

package com.company;

public class Main extends NumberManipulation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      NumberManipulation number = new NumberManipulation();
      number.getMaximum();
      number.getMinimum();

    }
}
```

I know that I can set an array to a fixed amount via:

```
double [] array = new double [10] //if I wanted the array to be 10 indexes
```

I can't figure out how to pass that into the getMin and getMax methods, though.

Just for the record, I was able to solve to the problem on my own. The recommendation provided with the link was not adequate for the answer. Here is a link it (https://gist.github.com/BrianARuff/4c49aee1a5644fee35e80b2547e6c74d)

Comment: Why do you need to pass it into the methods if it's declared at the class level?

Comment: I want to use "double [] array = new double [10] //if I wanted the array to be 10 indexes
" where the array is declared.

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: How do you currently call the `getMinimum()` and `getMaximum()` methods? Please show a complete program that we can compile and run. For more tips on creating a code example see [mcve].

Comment: main method posted

Comment: Are you asking how to pass arguments to methods? That's really basic material...

Comment: I know how to pass arguments. It turns out I was having problems with something else. I did figure it out though, here is the final code for this particular app (https://gist.github.com/BrianARuff/79907cd843550c11f46acc850240616c)

Answer (score -1):

I think you are searching something like this function

> Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, i, j);

Comment: I don't think so.